# Definition of "centroid" before the invention of vectors or coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

It is fairly easy to define the centroid of a finite set of points $v_1,...,v_n$ in $R^n$: $(v_1+...+v_n)/n$ will be it. But how do people *define*, or *calculate* the centroid of a set of point $v_1,..,v_n$ in 2D, or even 3D space, before the notion of vector or coordinate system is invented?

Comment: One could define the centroid in a vector-free, coordinate-free way by saying it is the unique point that minimizes the sum of squares of the distances to $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.  It's not a very helpful definition for calculation, though.  I also don't see an obvious way to prove that the minimum is unique without Cartesian geometry.

Comment: It's also the center of mass of $n$ bodies with equal mass.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some work on centroids in Euclid's Elements.

Comment: @user347489 Is there a good way to define center of mass without coordinates?  I don't know it.

Comment: @MaxPayne - How do you define adding $x_i$?

Comment: You could say that its the unique point that you can balance a flat object on. This paper might be interesting: http://www.jstor.org/stable/27956057?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @Batman Speaking of Euclid, when $n=3$ you can define centroid as the intersection of medians.  Is there a way to generalize this to $n>3$?  I guess drawing a line from each point to the center-of-mass of the other $n-1$ points should work as a recursive definition.  Provided the points are in g.p.

Comment: @MaxPayne Have you read the question or the title? :)

Comment: @ErickWong whoops. I am deleting the comments as they are of no use. Thanks ;)

Comment: @ErickWong - if n a power of 3, its straightforward to see that grouping any 3 points and replacing them with their centroid and doing that again and again would work. If you do all choices of groups (where one or two groups are 3 or 4, depending on if n is 1 or 2 mod 3), and do the same argument with all the centroids of those groups, you should be able to get it to work (the proof for n=4 is partitioning into triangles). Or something like that.

Comment: @Batman If you take all the centroids of all choices of groups, won't that be more points than you started with?

Comment: @ErickWong - Yes. The argument isn't precise, but you'd do all powers of 3 which doesn't have that problem. Then, you'd do the 3 or 4's and reduce. Another way is to do triangulations and stuff, which i think is equivalent to what you're proposing.

Answer (score 2):

The centroid of a set of points points can be defined recursively as follows:

- the centroid of a single point is the point itself;
- the centroid $G$ of points $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ ($n>1$) is the unique point on the segment joining the centroid $G'$ of $P_2,\ldots, P_n$ with $P_1$ such that: $GG'/GP_1=1/(n-1)$.

Of course one should prove that this definition does not depend on the order of points $P_1,\ldots, P_n$, which can be done (I can provide details if necessary).

This also entails the following useful property:

- the centroid $G$ of points $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ and $Q_1,\ldots, Q_m$ is the unique point on the segment joining the centroid $G_n$ of $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ with the centroid $G_m$ of $Q_1,\ldots, Q_n$ such that: $GG_m/GG_n=n/m$.